# How to set volume permission in docker container for non-root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am launch a jenkins docker container for CI work. And the host OS I am using is CoreOS. Inside the jenkins container, I also installed docker-cli in order to run build on docker containers in the host system. In order to do that, I use below configuration to mount `/var/run` on the jenkins container for mapper Docker socket:

```
volumes:
      - /jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
```

when I launch the container and run docker command, I got below error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The `/var/run` is root permission but my user is `jenkins`. How can I solve the permission issue to allow jenkins user to use docker command through mapper socket?

I have tried below command but the container doesn't allow me to run `sudo`:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing magical about permissions in Docker: they work just like permissions outside of Docker.  That is, if you want a user to have access to a file (like `/var/run/docker.sock`), then either that file needs to be owned by the user, or they need to be a member of the appropriate group, or the permissions on the file need to permit access to anybody.

Exposing `/var/run/docker.sock` to a non-root user is a little tricky, because typical solutions (just `chown`/`chmod` things from inside the container) will potentially break things on your host.

I suspect the best solution may be:

- Ensure that `/var/run/docker.sock` on your host is group-writable (e.g., create a `docker` group on your host and make sure that users in that group can use Docker).
- Pass the numeric group id of your `docker` group into the container as an environment variable.
- Have an ENTRYPOINT script in your container that runs as root that (a) creates a group with a matching numeric gid, and (b) modifies the Jenkins users to be a member of that group, and then (c) `exec` your docker `CMD` as the jenkins user.

So, your entrypoint script might look something like this (assuming that you have passed in a value for `$DOCKER_GROUP_ID` in your `docker-compose.yml`):

```
#!/bin/sh

groupadd -g $DOCKER_GROUP_ID docker
usermod -a -G docker jenkins

exec runuser -u jenkins "$@"
```

You would need to copy this into your image and add the appropriate `ENTRYPOINT` directive to your Dockerfile.

You may not have the `runuser` command. You can accomplish something similar using `sudo` or `su` or other similar commands.

Comment: I found that the container doesn't allow me to use `sudo` command.  I get below error when run sudo command: `We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: So you may need to configure it properly, or use another option.